# Issue with validating MQTT Client access token via broker using websockets

Tags: python, keycloak, mqtt

I was working on a prototype for security in MQTT based systems using a Raspberry Pi as my client and Keycloak as my authentication server (AS). I have managed to publish and subscribe to messages via Mosquitto broker without the authentication mechanism in place and have also successfully obtained the access token and token validation output from the keycloak validation endpoint.

However, when I implemented above sequence of tasks via a python script, to authenticate the mqtt client so it can publish/subscribe, I noticed that it is able to establish a connection but at the client end the connection closes. I suspect that this is due to the token not getting passed either due to wrong/invalid parameters or there is an issue with my token validation function

I would be really grateful if members can look at my python script and perhaps point out any errors or provide suggestions to improve my code. TIA!

```
import paho.mqtt.client as paho
import time
import sys
import json
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
broker="broker address"
port= 1884
sub_topic="test"

#-------------------------------------------------Function to get access token-----------------------------------------------------#

def get_token():
url = "https://token endpoint url"

    payload = 'grant_type=client_credentials'
    headers = {
    'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload, auth=HTTPBasicAuth("Client_ID","client_secret"))
    token = json.loads(response.text)
    return token["access_token"] 

mytoken = get_token()
print(mytoken)

#-----------------------------------------------------------Callback functions------------------------------------------------------#
def on_connect(client,userdata,flags, rc):
   print("Connected with code " +str(rc))
   client.subscribe(sub_topic)

def on_subscribe(client, userdata, mid, granted_qos):   #create function for callback
   print("subscribed with qos",granted_qos, "\n")
   pass
def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    print("message received  "  ,str(message.payload.decode("utf-8")))
def on_publish(client,userdata,mid):   #create function for callback
   print("data published mid=",mid, "\n")
   pass
def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):
   print("client disconnected")

#------------------------------------------------------------Connect to broker------------------------------------------------------#
client= paho.Client("Client",transport="websockets")       #create client object
#client.username_pw_set(username= "mytoken", password= "")
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_subscribe = on_subscribe       #assign function to callback
client.on_publish = on_publish        #assign function to callback
client.on_message = on_message        #assign function to callback
client.on_disconnect = on_disconnect

print("connecting to broker ",broker,"on port",port)
#client.connect("ws://broker.lailaafreen.com:1884")
client.connect(broker,port,60)           #establish connection

#--------------------------------Token validation-----------------------------------# 

def get_valid(token):
    url =  "https://validation endpoint url"
    payload = {}
    headers = {'content-type': "multipart/form-data", 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +mytoken}
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers)
    valid = json.loads(response.text)
    return valid
print(get_valid(get_token()))

#--------------------------------Publish/Subscribe----------------------------------#

client.loop_start()
print("subscribing to ",sub_topic)
#client.subscribe(sub_topic)
time.sleep(3)
client.publish("test","message")    #publish
time.sleep(4) 

client.disconnect()
```

UPDATE: Upon obtaining the access token and after attempting to connect to mosquitto broker, using the command:

`sudo mosquitto_pub -h broker_addr -p 1883 -i <acces_token> -t test -m "Hi"`

I get not authorised message:

```
Connection error: Connection Refused: not authorised.
Error: The connection was refused.
```

Below is my mosquitto configuration file:

```
persistence false
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

# Mosquitto Log File Destination
log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log
log_type all

# Adding Guman Readable Time Stamsps to /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log
log_timestamp true
log_timestamp_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S

# =================================================================
# Security
# =================================================================

allow_anonymous false

# =================================================================
# Listeners
# =================================================================

listener 1884
protocol websockets
socket_domain ipv4

listener 1883
protocol mqtt

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d
```

Comment: The call to `client.username_pw_set` is commented out? (and `mytoken` is in quotes so that exact text will be sent) - [minimal, reproducible, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please. What happens when you run this vs what do you expect (it appears to publish a message and then disconnect). Can you please also include the relevant Mosquitto logs. Note that your original question is still viewable (so you may want to cancel the token etc).

Comment: `Sending CONNACK to Laila_Raspi (0, 5)` the `5` is the reason code and means "Connection Refused, not authorized" (so its not surprising that the client disconnects).

Comment: Yes, I am aware what the 5 means here but I am not able to narrow down to what exactly is causing it. Could it be an incorrect (wrong format maybe?) parameter that is passed to the authentication server leading to the client not being authorised? or is there anything else I am not aware of?

Comment: "Could it be an incorrect" - we cannot tell because we don't have access to your authentication server and don't know how you have configured Mosquitto (and, as mentioned above, the code included does not even send the token). For testing retrieve a token and then try to connect with `mosquitto_pub` (the python code above is irrelevant until you have a working broker configuration).

Comment: @Brits I believe I have done what you suggested me to do and i am beginning to think this has something to do with my mosquitto installation with go-auth. opinion?

Comment: You had not mentioned `go-auth` previously; this probably should be the focus of your question (get things working with standard tools before trying anything more advanced). To help we would need your `/etc/mosquitto/conf.d/go-auth.conf` file contents, and you should enable logging (`auth_opt_log_level debug`) and include anything relevant in the question (if the logs don't provide you with the answer).